# The data reader is incompatible with the specified Model in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing my Application in MVC. I am using stored procedure to insert the values in the database. While adding the code in MVC i am getting an error.  I will share my code here.

WaitingList Table

```
[WaitingListId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Primary Key - [CustomerId] [int] NULL,
Foreign key - [BusinessCategoryId] [int] NULL,
Foreign key - [BusinessId] [int] NULL,
Foreign key - [LocationId] [int] NULL,
Foreign key - [EmployeeId] [int] NULL,
[WaitingOrder] [int] NULL,
[Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL
```

Stored Procedure

```
Alter procedure sp_waitinglist
@businessid int, 
@customerid int, 
@busictgryid int, 
@locid int, 
@empid int,
@sts nvarchar(50) 

As
declare @MaxVal as int
Begin

 If EXISTS(select * from tbl_WaitingList where BusinessId = @businessid )
 Begin

    SET @MaxVal = (SELECT MAX(WaitingOrder) +1 from tbl_WaitingList where BusinessId = @businessid )    
      insert into tbl_WaitingList(CustomerId, BusinessCategoryId,BusinessId,LocationId, EmployeeId, WaitingOrder, Status) values(@customerid, @busictgryid, @businessid,@locid,@empid,@MaxVal, 'yy')

    End

    else

     Begin
       SET @MaxVal= 1
     insert into tbl_WaitingList(CustomerId, BusinessCategoryId,BusinessId,LocationId, EmployeeId, WaitingOrder, Status) values(@customerid, @busictgryid, @businessid,@locid,@empid,@MaxVal, 'yy')
    End
End
```

MVC Controller Code

```
public ActionResult WaitingList()
        {
            SYTEntities ca = new SYTEntities();
            ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(ca.BusinessCategories.ToList(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
            ViewBag.Service = new SelectList(ca.tblBusinessCategories.ToList(), "BusinessID", "BusinessName");
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult WaitingList(string Business, string Service, string Location, string Employee)
        {
            ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.BusinessCategories.ToList(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
            ViewBag.Service = new SelectList(db.tblBusinessCategories.ToList(), "BusinessID", "BusinessName");

            var param = new SqlParameter[6];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@businessid", Value = Service };
            param[1] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@customerid", Value = (int)Session["UserID"] };
            param[2] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@busictgryid", Value = Business };
            param[3] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@locid", Value = Location };
            param[4] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@empid", Value = Employee };
           param[5] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@sts", Value =  "gg" };
            List<tbl_WaitingList> waiting = new List<tbl_WaitingList>();
            using (SYTEntities context = new SYTEntities())
            {
                waiting = context.Database.SqlQuery<tbl_WaitingList>("exec sp_waitinglist @businessid,@customerid,@busictgryid,@locid,@empid, @sts", param).ToList();


            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return View();

        }
```

View Page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("WaitingList", "Appt", FormMethod.Post))
{

 <div>
           @Html.DropDownList("Business", ViewBag.CategoryID as SelectList ,"Select the Business Category", new { id = "Business" })
       </div>
       <div>
           <label>Select the Service Type</label>
           @*<select id="Buname" name="buname" style="width:150px"></select>*@
           @Html.DropDownList("Service",  ViewBag.Service as SelectList,"Select", new { id = "Service", name ="buname"})
       </div>
       <div>
           <label> Select the Location</label>
           <select id="Location" name="location" style="width:150px"></select>
       </div>
       <div>
           <label> Select the Location</label>
           <select id="Employee" name="employee" style="width:150px"></select>
       </div>
  <div>
       <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Add me into waiting list"/>

   </div>
}
```

Error is

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'SYTModel.tbl_WaitingList'. A member of the type, 'WaitingListId', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

My Error Page is

[image]

I am getting an error like this. Can anyone please help me to solve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Instead of image, add the error description in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should supply the SqlParameter instances in the following way:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery<tbl_WaitingList>(
    "mySpName @param1, @param2, @param3",
    new SqlParameter("param1", param1),
    new SqlParameter("param2", param2),
    new SqlParameter("param3", param3)
);
```